# inject html using apache

Tags: html, apache

I have a portal that is under a virtual host in Apache. All lot of its .css and .js is generated dynamically by the underlying tomcat web application. What I want to do is inject some of my own .css and .js into the mix before it is served. I think I need something like mod_rewrite but for html.

I know I could try to piggyback onto some resource reference that is used on every page and use mod_rewrite that way, but that is hard to do and I need my css to be applied last.

Tell me there are some magic beans for this. I just need to inject a couple scripts and styles right at </head>.

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/questions/46449/how-to-inject-html-code-into-every-delivered-html-page

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it before, but it looks like [mod_ext_filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html) could do this

By looking at the example, you could try the following Perl script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $extraCode = "<script src=\"http:/...\"></script>";

while (<STDIN>) {
    s/<\/head>/$extraCode<\/head>/i;
    print;
}
```

After I posted this, I noticed someone recommended https://serverfault.com/questions/46449/how-to-inject-html-code-into-every-delivered-html-page. mod_proxy_html and mod_sed looks good

Comment: I ended up using mod_substitute and:

    `AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute "s|</body>|<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://blah.js\"></script></body>|ni"`

Though this doesn't work for some of my portals, but thankfully I found out how to hack them.